# Jquery finding closest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Something like this is my html code:

```
<div class="single-img"></div>
<h4>The title</h4>
<h4>The title 2</h4>
<div class="single-img"></div>

<div class="single-img"></div>
<h4>The title 3</h4>
<h4>The title 4</h4>
<div class="single-img"></div>
```

Then the jquery code is something like this:

```
$("h4").mouseenter(function() {
    //Find the closest div.single-img and add class "hover";        
}).mouseleave(function() {
    //Find the closest div.single-img and remove class "hover";
});
```

What I want is if I hover on h4 it will find the closer div.single-img and add class to it, it's either the previous div.single-img or the next div.single-img.

So for example if I hover on `<h4>The title</h4>` if will add class to the previous div.single-img then if I hover on `<h4>The title 2</h4>` it will add a class to the next div.single-img.

I've found that I cannot use the `.closest` because it's looking in the tree not siblings.

Comment: there are two `single-img` which one

Comment: So hovering over the first h4 would select the div before it and hovering over the second h4 would select the div after it?

Comment: Hi @j08691, Yes that's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a sample that will highlight the text in those sibling div's with blue when you hover over closes h4.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>
        .hover {
            color: blue
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("h4").mouseenter(function() {
                //Find the closest div.single-img and add class "hover";
                if ($(this).next().hasClass('single-img')) {
                    $(this).next().addClass('hover');
                } else if ($(this).prev().hasClass('single-img')) {
                    $(this).prev().addClass('hover');
                }
            }).mouseleave(function() {
                //Find the closest div.single-img and remove class "hover";
                if ($(this).next().hasClass('single-img')) {
                    $(this).next().removeClass('hover');
                } else if ($(this).prev().hasClass('single-img')) {
                    $(this).prev().removeClass('hover');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="single-img">Test Area 1</div>
<h4>The title</h4>
<h4>The title 2</h4>
<div class="single-img">Test Area 2</div>

<div class="single-img">Test Area 3</div>
<h4>The title 3</h4>
<h4>The title 4</h4>
<div class="single-img">Test Area 4</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I will try this one. :)

Comment: Thank youso much! It did worked as expected. In the mouseleave I only put $('.single-img').removeClass('hover');

Comment: Good stuff... glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("h4").prev("div.single-img")`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's `.index()` to find out the position of each element beneath a parent element, then find the distance between two of them by subtracting their indexes. When you take the absolute value `Math.abs(...)`, it ignores the negative sign (so it doesn't matter whether it comes before or after the target element).

Then just sort and return the element with the shortest distance. See the following example:

```js
var findNearestSib = function(element){
    var t = $(element);
    var ind = t.index();
    var sibs = t.siblings('div.single-img'); // Filter out target siblings
    
    var closest = sibs.map(function(i,e){
        var cur = $(e).index(); // Index of current element
        return {
            dist: Math.abs(cur - ind), // Distance between sibling and h4
            elem: e
        };
    }).toArray().sort(function(a,b){
        return a.dist - b.dist; // Sort by shortest distance
    });
    
    if(closest.length){
        return closest[0].elem; // Return nearest element
    }
}
$("h4").mouseenter(function() {
    $(findNearestSib(this)).addClass('hover');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(findNearestSib(this)).removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
div.single-img {
    background-color:blue;
    height:12px;
    border:2px solid white;
}
div.single-img.hover {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent-div">
    <div class="single-img"></div>
    <h4>The title</h4>
    <h4>The title 2</h4>
    <div class="single-img"></div>

    <div class="single-img"></div>
    <h4>The title 3</h4>
    <h4>The title 4</h4>
    <div class="single-img"></div>
</div>
```